# Apex Trigger that whenever account owner gets changed, send an email to previous account owner

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

Hello Everyone I wanted to write trigger that whenever account owner gets changed, send an email to previous account owner. and I wrote this trigger but working.

```
trigger SendEmail on Account (after update) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
       List<Messaging.Email> emailList = new List<Messaging.Email>();
   
       List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
       for(Account account : Trigger.new) {
           if(account.OwnerId != Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id).OwnerId) {
            accountIds.add(account.Id);
            }
        }
        if(accountIds.size() != Null ) {
            System.debug('accountIdsize****'+accountIds.size());
             Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
              String[] toAdress = new String[]{Account.owner.Email};
              System.debug('toAdress'+toAdress);
                  
                    emailMsg.setToAddresses(toAdress);
                    System.debug('toAdress'+toAdress);
                    String emailSub = 'Account Owner has been Changed';
                    emailMsg.setSubject(emailSub);
                    String disName = 'Abc Xyz';
                    emailMsg.setSenderDisplayName(disName);
                    String body = 'Dear';
                    body += 'One new contact created.';
                    emailMsg.setHtmlBody(body);
                    emailList.add(emailMsg);
                }
                Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
           }
       }
```

Can you please rectify and do let me know How can I send Email to the Previous account Owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the old data by using `trigger.old` context variable instead of `trigger.New`

The code should be like below.

```
    trigger SendEmail on Account (after update) {
  
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  //oldownerids variable is used to store the old owerid value of the current account
  List<ID>oldownerids=new List<ID>();
  // sendTo valiable is used to store the emails of the users to whom you need to send an email
  List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
  
  If(trigger.Isafter && trigger.Isupdate){
 
   for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
  // here oldacc variable is used to get the old data of the current account 
     Account oldacc = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
    //below if condition need to compare the old value and new value of current account record
      if (acc.ownerid != oldacc.ownerid ) {  
       oldownerids.add(oldacc.ownerid);     
        }
      }
    }
    
    // iterating the users to get the list of user emails
  for(user u: [select id,email from user where id IN:oldownerids]){
   sendTo.add(u.Email);
   }
   
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     
      emailMsg.setSenderDisplayName('Abc Xyz');
      emailMsg.setSubject('Owner change');
      String body = 'Account Owner has been Changed';
      //here you are setting the setToAddresses value from sendTo variable
      emailMsg.setToAddresses(sendTo);
      emailMsg.setHtmlBody(body);
      mails.add(emailMsg);
      try{
      Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
      system.debug('--exception--'+e);
       
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Ankaiah Bandi That is working for me!